# JQuery does not load effect obtained through a service

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'll try to explain my problem as best as possible.

I have a page made in HTML and have a service written in Java that returns me a html.

That my html page use an ajax function to load the data from this service until then works fine, but I have some effect when the user clicks open a div using JQuery does not work.

Is it coz I'm bringing the html else he's not carrying anything?

Here the page with the service working: [LiNK](http://williamvillar.com.br/assets/Detalhe.html?valorAplicado=100000&meses=24&selic=14.15&di=14.13&txAdmin=2&td=0.20&cdb=117&cdb_pre=15.5&lci=92&fundo=104&pagina=detalhe)

Here the static page without  [LINK 2](http://williamvillar.com.br/assets/simulacao_detalhado.html) Service

Click + to the tests.

Comment: Can you post the JS that enables the button clicks and the AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Thus resolved, it is a tip for future research.

The file must be loaded after the end of the ajax request, but the elements will not have their listeners loaded, ie does not detect clicks.

```
 $.getScript( "/assets/js/materialize.min.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
```

});